# Castle not resolving sub dependency with TypedFactory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have an interface to use for a factory using Castle's TypedFactoryFacility which takes a string.

```
public interface IFoo<T> {}
public interface IBar1 : IFoo<IBar1> {}
public interface IBar2 : IFoo<IBar2> {}

public class MyClass1 : IBar1 {}
public class MyClass2 : IBar2 {}

public interface IFactory<T> where T : IFoo<T>
{
    T Create(string primitive2);
}
```

Both MyClasses have a sub-dependency:

```
public class SubDependency : ISubDependency
{
    public SubDependency(string primitive1, string primitive2)
}
```

I want to install all the MyClasses in a given namespace based on IFoo<> but I want the instances requested and resolved by the IBar interfaces. So both interfaces have to be registered and resolve to the same instance of the same class.

Here is my installer code:

```
// register foo
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(IFoo<>))
        .InSameNamespaceAs(typeof(IFoo<>))
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
        .LifeStyleHybridPerWebRequestTransient());

// register factory
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(IFactory<>)).AsFactory()
        .LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient());

// register sub dependency
container.Register(
    Component.For<ISubDependency>().ImplementedBy<SubDependency>()
        .LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient()
        .DependsOn(new
        {
            primitive1 = "this resolves"
        }));
```

Then I register my container like this:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

var factory = container.Resolve<IFactory<IBar1>>();
var myClass1 = factory.Create("primitive2: this does not resolve");
```

When I look at the container it shows that it has registered everything (though I'm not sure if it's registered correctly).

I get the following error:

`Could not resolve non-optional dependency for 'SubDependency' (SubDependency). Parameter 'primitive2' type 'System.String'`

I thought the container was supposed to pass the parameter from the factory to all sub dependencies that had arguments with the same name. How do I get this to resolve correctly, where I can define one value in the installer and supply the other at run-time?

**UPDATE:**
Although my answer below works I get some container warnings I'm not sure how to resolve:

```
All components are potentially misconfigured (except for the IFactory): scope
Components with potential duplicated dependencies: SubDependency, TypedFactoryComponentSelector
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, though it seems like a terrible hack, so it would be great to get some guidance.

I changed my IFoo<> registration to:

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(IFoo<>))
        .InSameNamespaceAs(typeof(IFoo<>))
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
        .LifeStyleHybridPerWebRequestTransient()
        .Configure(r => r.DynamicParameters((k, d) =>
        {
            var subDependency = k.Resolve<ISubDependency>(d);
            d.Add("subDepedency", subDependency); 
        })));
```

This works, but I don't like it and I hope there's a better way. This requires that all classes that have SubDependency as a dependency name it "subDependency", for instance:

```
public class MyClass1 : IBar1
{
    public MyClass1(SubDependency subDependency) // <-- MUST be named that.
}
```

I'm not sure if I've caused more problems then solved with this solution. Is there an easier way to make it so the TypedFactory parameter gets propagated to all sub-dependencies that have an argument with that name?

Comment: Even though this answer works I decided to go a different route and will probably end up creating a new question.